# Does Gödel say unprovable statements exist, or that they can exist?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I don't have a very strong mathematical background, but the question I have is straightforward.

[Numberphile's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4ndIDcDSGc) video and [Veritasium's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeQX2HjkcNo&t) video are giving different answers regarding the final conclusion of Gödel's incompleteness theorem.

What does this theorem state ?

- Unprovables statement exists within an axiom-based system ?
- Unprovables statements CAN exist within an axiom-based system ?

Comment: It says that within a consistent logical system that is capable of modeling the natural numbers, there exists a statement such that neither it nor its negation is provable.

Comment: I think you have to take care what is being assumed - if the system is (a) sufficiently powerful and (b) consistent then ... . But you can easily create an inconsistent system by declaring every statement to be an axiom (and therefore  trivially provable).

Comment: Frankly speaking, while I like both youtube channels, neither of their Gödel videos is good.

Comment: Read the puzzle starting on pgae 193 [here](http://www.logic-books.info/sites/default/files/lady-or-the-tiger-and-other-logic-puzzles.pdf) and its solution on page 201, for a remarkably clear non-technical presentation of the essence of Gödel's proof.   Then you might want to read the previous chapter, which describes it in more detail.

Comment: I must strongly agree with @DonThousand. Goedel's Theorems are very easy to misunderstand and to misrepresent. These are theorems about the interplay between syntax and semantics, between provability and validity. There is already an aura of mysticism around the (incompleteness) theorems, and I don't find the videos do a good job demystifying the situation. In some sense, it is the completeness theorem that is much more important and interesting than the incompleteness ones. But it gets little glory, since it's not quite so cool sounding.

Comment: dear @DonThousand, in your first comment you are missing the hypothesis that the system be *recursively enumerable* as well; otherwise, for example, just let your system be "true arithmetic", ie the complete theory of the structure $(\mathbb{N},\cdot,+)$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Completely correct. I didn't know exactly how detailed I wanted to be in a comment.

Comment: A good proof of Gödel's Incompleteness theorem gives a way of translating a recursive proof system for arithmetic into the formula in that proof system "this formula has no proof". This is an explicit example of an unprovable statement, and exists as long as the pieces necessary for the construction (the proof system is recursive and can do enough arithmetic to do coding arguments) are there.

Comment: It says that for a sufficiently descriptive language, for any sound logic (that part is informal, originally it was for a specific logic but it was fairly clear the choice of logic didn't matter) there is a statement that is true but not provable.  Anyway, you shouldn't study Godel until you've spent years proving things informally in mathematics and probably a year at least using a formal logic to prove things.  Walk before you can run.

Comment: $(1)$ If you want to make progress in mathematics, avoid online videos. Read wikipedia- and pdf-articles. $(2)$ Goedel's first incompleteness theorem states that every consistent theory that is strong enough to satisfy the representation theorem (at least as strong as the peano axioms) necessarily contains true, but unprovable stataments. It is both crucial that the theory is consistent and strong enough.

Comment: If the theory is too weak , it can be provably consistent and complete (Presburger arithmetics is an example). If it is inconsistent, it can prove everything (and is therefore completely useless).